# Consulta sobre Video View en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

que tal tengo una pequeña duda existencial jejejej estoy averiguando a cerca de android studio y me encuentro con lo que es video view para cargar videos con URL quemadas en codigo y cosas asi , la cosa es si hay alguna forma de que el video collapse como lo hace en youtube es decir esa animacion como que se minimiza , hay alguna forma de hacer eso ??

Comment: Posible duplicado de: [como poner mini pantalla en android como youtube o twitch?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152181/como-poner-mini-pantalla-en-android-como-youtube-o-twitch), no se muestra nada de código y es demasiado amplia.

Comment: "Estudiantes de ISAC", te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,